# Alfresco: Show "edit metadata"-popup after upload

Tags: upload, metadata, edit, alfresco, required

We want the user to be able to edit the metadata after uploading a file to Alfresco. Ideally, we would also like this to work when uploading multiple files (for example through Flash or through HTML5).

We would like to be redirected to the "Edit metadata"-screen after uploading, or show the "Edit metadata"-popup. Either of those.

Or maybe we can make it so that the metadata can be entered before uploading?

The idea is to have documents that can expire. So the expiration-date is a required field in the metadata. However, when we configure this to be required, we can't upload because the expiration-date is not set.

I hope anyone can send us in the right direction regarding this, as we are breaking our heads over it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for the expiration-date property, you could just use an Alfresco inbound rule, that adds the expiration-date property on every uploaded file, and puts a fake value inside (like 01-01-1070 for example).
Then you could use a custom edit-metadata webscript to alter that value right after the upload, together with all the other values.

Answer (score 1):

This Alfresco plugin prompts for a content type and for metadata during the upload:

http://softwareloop.com/uploader-plus-an-alfresco-uploader-that-prompts-for-metadata/

Every folder can be configured to allow only certain content types.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below link as reference to customize Flash upload component of alfresco share.

http://www.ixxus.com/blog201109customising-upload-files-dialog-alfresco-share/

In the bottom of dialog you can add table which will display textbox, so user can add values from that table.